# shared library method definition with Map

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I checked few jenkins shared library examples and I found that in some of them the call method define as below:

```groovy
def call (Map parameters) { .... }
```

and in other:

```groovy
def call (Map parameters = [:]) { .... }
```

What is the difference between definition of parameters with `=[:]` and without it ?

Answer (score 2):

Groovy supports a feature feature is called [default arguments](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_default_arguments)

The first example requires you to pass in a value for the parameter.

```groovy
call(['key': 'value'])
```

The second example can be called that way, but it can also be called without specifying a value and it will use the default:

```groovy
call()
```